# How to recover from Django Celery dropped connection to Postgres

Tags: django, postgresql, django-celery

I'm running Django Celery with a Redis broker and a Database Results backend, the same Postgres DB that I am using for the main Application.

Recently I have hit a situation where the Postgres server is restarted and the worker processes lose their DB connection. After this happens no celery tasks succeed again, even once the DB is back and the main Django site is responding normally. I need to restart the celeryd processes before anything is processed. All celery tasks report the same error:

```
DatabaseError: terminating connection due to administrator command
SSL connection has been closed unexpectedly
```

I understand that when using the db results backend Celery is unable to report the failure and so externally it appears that those tasks were never executed but I don't understand why subsequent tasks fail. The Celery docs say that it doesn't persist DB connections between tasks so a new task should establish a new connection.

So, why would this happen? Is there some lower level persistence of the db connection? How can I have celery retry these tasks?

Comment: Not sure if it's entirely related, but I've had this bug with Django before: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/15802

Comment: seems related, but in my case I would have expected celery to close the connection explicitly and the next task to function correctly but that's not happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this by adding an after_return handler to all my celery tasks to close the DB connection after each execution.

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#abstract-classes

```
class DBTask(celery.Task):
    abstract = True

    def after_return(self, *args, **kwargs):
        connection.close()

@celery.task(base=DBTask)
def mytask():
    # Do Stuff with DB
```